# Wordpress Not Working On Nginx Server

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

You will have to bear with me here while I try and explain this the best I can.

I am working with a nginx server that I did not set up, I have very little knowledge of nginx. I have set up a new wordpress website which lives under the following url structure `subsubdomain.subdomain.domain.com/website/` it is important that the full wordpress website is functional within the `/website/` directory.

I have the site set up and the home page works perfectly when I navigate to `subsubdomain.subdomain.domain.com/website/`, but when I navigate to a subpage `subsubdomain.subdomain.domain.com/website/resources/` the server throws `File not found`.

From my little knowledge of nginx I think this is a file permissions issue, I have logged into the server and run the following command `sudo chmod 777 -R /path/to/website` and also done `sudo chown www:www -R /path/to/website` to try and give full access. Unfortunately this has not worked either.

When checking the website `access_log` and `error_log`, they are empty. I then checked the nginx main log file and found the following error:

```
2018/05/31 04:07:42 [crit] 32426#0: *120 open() "/usr/share/nginx//var/www/sites-running/subsubdomain.subdomain.website.com/logs/nginx.access.log" failed (2: No such file or directory) while logging request, client: **.***.***.***, server: *.subdomain.domain.com, request: "GET /website/resources/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "subsubdomain.subdomain.domain.com", referrer: "http://subsubdomain.subdomain.domain.com/website/"
```

I'll be honest with you guys, this means nothing to me. All I can see is that it looks like the path to the log file is bad. So I went to my website `nginx-vhost.conf` file to see how it is defined and I have the following code:

```
access_log /var/www/sites-running/subsubdomain.subdomain.website.com/logs/nginx.access.log
```

Which looks all good to me.

So now I am stuck, I have no idea how to fix this so if anyone can make some sense of this and can help me out that would be amazing.

Cheers,
Luke.

**UPDATE**

I have just run `nginx -V` and noticed that there is a value called `prefix`, here is the value:

```
--prefix=/usr/share/nginx
```

It looks like this could be my problem but I have no idea what this is, how it is used and do not know the damage i could cause if I change it.

**UPDATE**

Here is my website nginx-vhost.conf file.

```
# Nginx configuration for Website
# This is for development purposes
server{
    listen       80;
    server_name  subsubdomain.subdomain.domain.com;
    set $site_root "/var/www/sites-available/$host";
    set $public_html "$site_root/public_html";
    set $logs_dir "$site_root/logs";
    set $nginx_root "$site_root/webapps/ROOT";
    root $nginx_root;

    error_log /var/www/sites-available/subsubdomain.subdomain.domain.com/logs/nginx.error.log;
    access_log /var/www/sites-available/subsubdomain.subdomain.domain.com/logs/nginx.access.log  main;

    index index.php;
    #default_type text/html;
    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    #add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "*";

    # ------------------------------------------------------
    #
    # static resources routing for version control on assets
    #
    # ------------------------------------------------------
    #location ~ ^/static/([^/]+)/(content|resources)/(.*)$ {
    #    alias $public_html/$2/$3;
    #}
    #location ~ ^/content/(.*)$ {
    #    alias $public_html/content/$1;
    #}

    location / {
        # This is cool because no php is touched for static content.
        # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break when using query string
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

    }

    location /wp-admin {
            # This is cool because no php is touched for static content.
            # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break when using query string
          try_files $uri $uri/ /wp-admin/index.php?$args;
    }

    # ----------------------------------------
    #
    #   PHP
    #
    # ----------------------------------------
    location ~ \.php {
        #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $host;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param CONTENT_ROOT $public_html/content;
        fastcgi_param CONTENT_UPLOAD_DIR $public_html/content;
        fastcgi_param LOGS_ROOT $logs_dir;
        fastcgi_param app.profile staging;
        fastcgi_param APP_MODE staging;
        fastcgi_param DB_NAME **********;
        fastcgi_param DB_USER **********;
        fastcgi_param DB_PASS **********;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }

}
```

Here is my main nginx.conf file

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

#gzip  on;
    client_max_body_size 100m;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    index   index.html index.htm;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
        #root         /var/www/sites-running/nginx-default;
        #index index.html index.htm;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
        }

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /40x.html
        #
        error_page  404              /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
        }

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }

# proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;
    #    root         html;

    #    location / {
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443;
    #    server_name  localhost;
    #    root         html;

    #    ssl                  on;
    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    #    location / {
    #    }
    #}

}
```

Comment: If you expect to get some help then you need to share your nginx.conf

Comment: Can you share your hosts file? So we can see the index.php rule you have. https://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx you need to check that and also what is the Site URL in the admin setup as

Comment: @AlexC & @TheBlackBenzKid - I have added my configuration file, i think that is what you were both asking for. As this is a deployment from a local wordpress site to a staging wordpress site I did a find and replace in the database changing `http://localhost:8888/` to `http://subsubdomain.subdomain.domain.com/website/`

Comment: Not saying it's your problem here, but after such a search/replace, make sure you flush the rewrite rules by clicking save on the permalink-settings page. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules

Comment: @ippi - That's a good suggestion and something I would usually do but I am not currently able to access the admin area as when I put the admin url in I just get shown `File not found` by the server.

Comment: if the website comes up, you can add `flush_rewrite_rules();` in your functions.php (or whatever), refresh once and then remove it.

Comment: @ippi - I tried adding `flush_rewrite_rules();` to my `functions.php` and loaded the homepage, but this didn't change anything. I also ran `sudo nginx -t` and got the following result `nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok`
`nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful` so no help there unfortunately.

Comment: What about this then. `try_files $uri $uri/ /wp-admin/index.php?$args;`  into `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;`  . Still guesswork though

Comment: @ippi - Very close, I have just managed to figure it out, I had to add the following `try_files $uri $uri/website/ /website/index.php?$args;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for their help. I have finally managed to figure out what was going wrong. I needed to update my conf file to have a second location statement which looked inside of the `/website/` folder.

like so:

```
location /website/ {
    # This is cool because no php is touched for static content.
    # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break when using query string
    try_files $uri $uri/website/ /website/index.php?$args;

}
```

Here is my full nginx-vhost.conf file:

```
# Nginx configuration for Website
# This is for development purposes
server{
    listen       80;
    server_name  subsubdomain.subdomain.domain.com;
    set $site_root "/var/www/sites-available/$host";
    set $public_html "$site_root/public_html";
    set $logs_dir "$site_root/logs";
    set $nginx_root "$site_root/webapps/ROOT";
    root $nginx_root;

    error_log /var/www/sites-available/subsubdomain.subdomain.domain.com/logs/nginx.error.log;
    access_log /var/www/sites-available/subsubdomain.subdomain.domain.com/logs/nginx.access.log  main;

    index index.php;
    #default_type text/html;

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    #add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "*";

    # ------------------------------------------------------
    #
    # static resources routing for version control on assets
    #
    # ------------------------------------------------------
    #location ~ ^/static/([^/]+)/(content|resources)/(.*)$ {
    #    alias $public_html/$2/$3;
    #}
    #location ~ ^/content/(.*)$ {
    #    alias $public_html/content/$1;
    #}



    location /website/ {
        # This is cool because no php is touched for static content.
        # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break when using query string
        try_files $uri $uri/website/ /website/index.php?$args;

    }

    location / {
        # This is cool because no php is touched for static content.
        # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break when using query string
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

    }

    location /wp-admin {
            # This is cool because no php is touched for static content.
            # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break when using query string
            try_files $uri $uri/ /wp-admin/index.php?$args;
    }

    # ----------------------------------------
    #
    #   PHP
    #
    # ----------------------------------------
    location ~ \.php {
        #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $host;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param CONTENT_ROOT $public_html/content;
        fastcgi_param CONTENT_UPLOAD_DIR $public_html/content;
        fastcgi_param LOGS_ROOT $logs_dir;
        fastcgi_param app.profile staging;
        fastcgi_param APP_MODE staging;
        fastcgi_param DB_NAME **********;
        fastcgi_param DB_USER **********;;
        fastcgi_param DB_PASS **********;;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }

}
```